# How to check the state of input event?

Tags: javascript, dom, slider, dom-events, rangeslider

In javascript a event listener can be made for a range slider by

```
document.getElementById().on("input", () =>{event handler})
```

However I cannot seem to find the according boolean value for that input event, for example with check boxes you can do

```
document.getElementById().checked
```

which returns a boolean value that tells you if the box is checked (selected).

I have searched in the nodelink with `getelementbyname` of the slider, no traces can be found of the state of input event, except for `inputmode`, also tried `document.getElementById().input` and `oninput`, which does not work as well.

The point is a condition of an if-statement outside the eventlistener, since I have different values as argument for the called function, when the slider is moved (input event triggered) that default value function should not be called. Follow along the example of the check event state: `if (document.getElementById('id').checked == true) {code} else {default function is called}`. Is it also possible to check the input event state?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly, you need to get a boolean whenever the event is triggered and false when the input is empty, if that is it, you can do it like that:

```
document.querySelector('class-or-ID').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  if (!event.target.value) {
    // input is empty
  } else {
    // input has content
  }
});
```

Comment: The point is a condition of an if-statement outside the eventlistener, since I have different values as argument for the called function, when the slider is moved (input event triggered) that default value function should not be called. Follow along the example of the check event state: if (document.getElementById('id').checked == true) {code} else {default function is called}. Is it also possible to check the input event state?

Answer (score 0):

In general a range slider will not have a simple true/false value since a range slider represents exactly that: a range of values. If you are just trying to get the value of the slider when it is changed you can do something like:

```
document.getElementById('...').addEventSlistener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value); // logs numeric value of the slider
});
```

Note that if you use the `change` event instead of `input` you will only get the value when it is 'released' by the user. The `input` event will fire as the slider is being dragged by the user.